Como exibir o item que corresponde à pesquisa no HTML
Eu fiz o seguinte código:
<!-- ----- -->
    <input id="search" autocaptalize type="search" list="pesquisa">
    <datalist id="pesquisa">
        
        <option value="Cotton Candy"></option>
        <option value="House"></option>
        <option value="Sexy"></option>
        
    </datalist>
<!-- ----- -->
    
    <div class="layout">
        
        <h1>Cotton candy</h1>
        <div class="pallet">
            
            <div class="block">
               <div class="color" style="--color: #feeceb">.</div>
               #FEECEB
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="color" style="--color: #e9fefe">.</div>
                #E9FEFE
            </div>
            <div class="block">  
                <div class="color" style="--color: #e9fee9">.</div>
                #E9FEE9
            </div>
                <div class="block">
                <div class="color" style="--color: #e9e9fe">.</div>
            #E9E9FE
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <!-- +++++ -->
    <div class="layout">
        
        <h1>House</h1>
        <div class="pallet">
            
            <div class="block">
               <div class="color" style="--color: #f4d7a4">.</div> 
               #F4D7A4
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="color" style="--color: #cda274">.</div>
                #CDA274
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="color" style="--color: #f0e5d6">.</div>
                #F0E5D6
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="color" style="--color: #533c2b">.</div>
                #533C2B
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <!-- +++++ -->
    <div class="layout">
        
        <h1>Sexy</h1>
        <div class="pallet">
            
            <div class="block">
               <div class="color" style="--color: #650000">.</div> 
               #650000
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="color" style="--color: #8d313c">.</div>
                #8D313C
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="color" style="--color: #9b191a">.</div>
                #9B191A
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <div class="color" style="--color: #ba675e">.</div>
                #BA675E
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>

Aqui, tem três paletas de cores, e um input para pesquisar com as opções do nome de cada paleta. O que eu quero fazer é que quando o usuário pesquisar algo, apenas a/s paleta/s que corresponde/m ao nome pesquisado apareçam, mas não sei como fazer isso! Se alguém tiver alguma ideia e puder me explicar, serei muito grato!

Pode importar o JQuery e no evento "keyup" do input mostrar ou esconder as paletas se o título for igual ao termo pesquisado.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".layout").hide();

        $('#search').on('keyup', function(){
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            
            $(".layout").each(function(){
                var title = $(this).find('h1').text().toLowerCase();
                if(title == value){
                    $(this).show();
                }else{
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>

